# Duda formato numerico en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

que diferencia hay entre una variable asi.

```
$numero = 1;
```

y un numero que venga desde esta forma.

```
$valorusuario = $request->numero;
```

Hay manera de que el numero que viene de `$valorusuario` lo pueda convertir a al formato que tiene la variable `$numero`?

lo converti en int, pero sigo igual

```html
     /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function selectord(Request $request)
    {

        $valorusuario = $request->valorusuario;
        $int = (intval(var))$valorusuario;

        $numero = 1;
       
     
        $consultarea=usuarios::where('user_id', $numero)->paginate(2);
        $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return view('usuario.consultareas',compact('consultarea','usuariosOpciones'));
      
    }
```

si por ejemplo uso una variable simple como $numero, el paginado funciona perfecto, pero si uso la variable $int que converti, este me carga la primera pagina pero no las siguientes, no entiendo cual pueda ser la diferencia para que est o ocurra.

Comment: convertir lo que llegue a `$valorusuario` a tipo `int` asumiendo que a `$numero` le llegue un  1

Comment: Gracias shadow, es verdad lo que dices, de echo lo hice pero sigo con el mismo problema, mira lo que actualice arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Debido a los 4 posts que ya has creado tratando el mismo tema (por favor solo actualiza uno, no crees varios), Puedo deducir que lo que pasa es que cuando pasas a la página 2, el valor de `$request->valorusuario` se vuelve nulo.
Por lo que tu query no devolverá datos al convertirse en:

> Usuarios::where('user_id', **null**)->paginate(2);

Para solucionar tu problema, agrega a tu paginate: `->appends(['valorusuario' => $valorusuario]);`

Quedaría asi:

```
$valorusuario = $request->valorusuario;
$consultarea=usuarios::where('user_id', $numero)->paginate(2)->appends(['valorusuario' => $valorusuario]);
```